# category pages are not opened properly

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

I am working on magento-1.9 website. Here, category pages are not opening properly.

Comment: Please check error log.

Comment: Could you provide more details. Like what's not working properly? the images? the filters? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In root of magento, you can see index.php file, you can uncomment these lines in that file : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` ,

Then you can see the real errors that causing the problem

Comment: Or in root of magento, you can see index.php file, you can uncomment these lines in that file : #ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1); , Than you can see the real errors that causing the problem.

Comment: I have just edited Description. plz click on my url.

Comment: Please apply above2 solution and let me know . First apply this two solution

Comment: Good , @murtuza, plz add this solution as answer. i removed the dailydeal, so error happend, now i enabled that, working fine. but i knew the solution based on yoour answer. plz add answer properly based on my comment, i will upvote Good job.